# how do i connect azure database with google spreadsheet script?

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, google-sheets, azure-sql-database, ssms

I created a user in the sql server manager studio with db_reader role , and i tried to connect with google spreadsheet with script with this code:

```
   function AcessaVendas () {
   var URL = 'jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433'
   var USER = 'visitant'
   var PASS = '*******'
   var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);  
   var stmt = conn.createStatement();
   stmt.setMaxRows(10000);
   var start = new Date(); 
   var rs = stmt.executeQuery( myquery());
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dados");
   ss.getRange('a2:h1000').clearContent();
   var cell = ss.getRange('a2');
   var row = 0;
   while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < 11; col++) {
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
   }
  row++;
}
 rs.close();
 stmt.close();
 conn.close();
 var end = new Date();
 Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

but  this error always appears:"Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."

i already tried by opening ip 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255
someone could show me where did i make a mistake?

Comment: i created a similar post  with less things because i saw that there were many things wrong

Comment: I am sorry. Hope you find answers.

Comment: Can you connect from SSMS?

Comment: yes i can connect with SSMS

Comment: Is port 1433 open on the client that runs the application?

Answer (score 2):

Managed to find the right connection string. See below :

```
var servername = 'servername'
var user = 'username';
var userPwd = 'password';
var db = 'dbname';
var userString = user + '@' + servername
var connectionString = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + servername + '.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=' + db

var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(connectionString,userString,userPwd);
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This code works well: to connect Azure database and grab data from table

```
function onOpen() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Get Data', functionName: 'readData'}
];
    spreadsheet.addMenu('Report', menuItems);
}


// Replace the variables in this block with your values. Port ':1433' is not necessary
 var hostName = 'SERVER.database.windows.net:1433;'
 var db = 'DBNAME;';
 var user = 'USER@SERVER';
 var userPwd = 'PASSWORD';



 var dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://'+hostName + 'databaseName='+db; 


function readData() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();


 // Place your query below
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT TOP (10) * FROM [dbo].[NAME]');
 var metaData=results.getMetaData();
 var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 sheet.clearContents();

 var arr=[];

 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
  arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
 }

 sheet.appendRow(arr);


 while (results.next()) {
  arr=[];

  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {

   arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
  }
 sheet.appendRow(arr);

}

results.close();
stmt.close();

sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, numCols+1);

}
```